# How to package a header-only C++ library for iOS with Bazel?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, bazel, objective-c++

I'm working on a header-only C++ library with several dependencies (xtensor, fmtlib, Boost, Accelerate.framework) using Bazel as the build system. There is a currently a single class whose interface I'd like to expose to an iOS app (to be) written in Objective-C++.

---

I have tried using something along the lines of the following configuration:

`BUILD`:

```
package(
    default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

ios_static_framework(
    name = "MyFramework",
    hdrs = ["objc_lib.h"],
    deps = [":objc_lib"],
    families = ["iphone"],
    minimum_os_version = "12.0",
)

objc_library(
    name = "objc_lib",
    hdrs = ["objc_lib.h"],
    non_arc_srcs = ["objc_lib.mm"],
    deps = [":cc_lib"],
    sdk_frameworks = ["Accelerate"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "cc_lib",
    hdrs = ["cc_lib.hpp"],
    deps = [
        # several header-only targets
        ":dep1",
        ":dep2",
    ],
)

...
```

`cc_lib.hpp`:

```
#include "dep1.hpp"
#include "dep2.hpp"

class MyClass {
// ...
};
```

`objc_lib.h`:

```
#include "cc_lib.hpp"
```

`objc_lib.mm`:

```
#include "objc_lib.h"
```

Running `bazel build //...` produces a framework archive with the following structure that doesn't have any of the headers of `objc_lib`'s transitive dependencies.

```
MyFramework.framework
├── Headers
│   ├── MyFramework.h
│   └── objc_lib.h
├── Modules
│   └── module.modulemap
└── MyFramework
```

---

Is there a "canonical" way of packaging a header-only library for iOS (as a framework or otherwise) with Bazel?